# Tengo que ingresar dos veces el usuario y password para ingresar al sistema

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tengo una página index.php para ingreso de usuario y clave que valido sus campos con jquery.validate y de igual con esta información obtengo el acceso al sistema, pero siempre debo tipear dos veces el usuario y password para acceder y eso genera problemas con los usuarios... todo funcionaba de maravilla, pero tuve que pasar mi codigo a un nuevo hosting y me manifiestan que es error de header, pero realmente ya no se que es... ahí les paso parte del código para su ayuda.

**index.php**

```
<form role="form" id="acceso" name="acceso">
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <label class="block clearfix">
                                                <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" value="" />
                                                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                                </span>
                                            </label>

                                            <label class="block clearfix">
                                                <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="" />
                                                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-lock"></i>
                                                </span>
                                            </label>

                                            <div class="space"></div>

                                            <div class="clearfix">
                                                <button id="btn-ingresar" name="btn-ingresar" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Ingresar</button>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="space-4"></div>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </form>
```

**login.validate.js**

```
$if(msj == 9){
                                                        $(form).find('#btn-ingresar').attr("disabled", "disabled").attr("value", "Ingresando...");
                                                        $('#alertBoxes').html('<div class="alert alert-success"></div>');
                                                        $('.alert-success').hide(0).html('Acceso correcto, ingresando al sistema...');
                                                        $('.alert-success').slideDown(timeSlide);
                                                        setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = "home.php?c=index"; },(timeSlide + 1000));


                                    }
```

debería ejecutar todo y redireccionar a la pagina home.php?c=index, pero regresa a index.php para volver a ingresar la información y luego ingresa al sistema sin problema alguno... Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Difícil lo pones ayudarte con esas pocas lineas de código.

Cuando cargas el jquery de validación?

Echale un vistazo a esto:
https://lenguajehtml.com/p/html/formularios/validaciones-html5

Es muy posible que te este dando otros errores el código. Verifica con el inspector de código de tu navegador que no haya más errores.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español, te recomiendo que des una vuelta por [¿Cómo Responder?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que logres ayudar a quienes preguntan!

Comment: El tema es el siguiente, en las lineas finales del index.php incluyo la libreria de jquery.validate.js y de igual manera login.validate.js y claro el sistema funciona correctamente, pero al loguear los usuarios estos tipean dos veces su usuario y password, claro luego ingresan sin problema entonces pienso que el problema radica en la parte de redirigir a la pantalla principal desde el login.validate.js que solo ejecuta las lineas enviadas ya que el nueve (9) es el codigo de haber pasado todas las validaciones de usuario, clave, activo, etc. etc.

Comment: Y si cargas primero el jquery y el login.validate.js antes que cargue el formulario html. ¿funciona correcto?

Comment: Estimado Dr.Manhattan, procedí a realizar los que me indicas y coloque el jquery y el login.validate en las primeras instrucciones de mi proyecto, es decir antes del <head> de la pantalla de index.php pero mantiene el mismo comportamiento de ingresar dos veces usuario y password para acceder al sistema.